# Spark Integration with hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, azure-hdinsight

Currently in our project we are using HDInsights 3.6 in which we have spark and hive integration enabled by default as both shares the same catalogs. Now we want to migrate HDInsights 4.0 where spark and hive will be having different catalogs . I had a go through the Microsoft document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/interactive-query/apache-hive-warehouse-connector) where we need additional cluster required to integrate with help of Hive warehouse connector. Now i wanted to know if there is any other approach instead of using extra cluster .Any suggestions will be highly appreciable.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using external tables, they can point both Spark and Hive to use same metastore. This only applies to external tables .